# Change text size of a Widget app

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I have a PreferenceActivity where user can select the size for a TextView of a Widget app. The activity is called when the Widget is pressed. I'm setting the text size in OnPause, but it isn't working. Is something wrong with the code?

```
    public class WidgetSettings extends PreferenceActivity 
{
    private int mAppWidgetId = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.widget_setttings_layout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

            mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }
}

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        super.onPause();
        float textSize = Float.parseFloat(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("batteryTextSize", "12"));

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());

        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(getBaseContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        remoteView.setFloat(R.id.textView1, "setTextSize", 22);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, remoteView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the text size in onPause()?  onPause() runs, surprisingly enough, when the application pauses, so your user would have to wait until the device times out and goes to sleep or you bring some other activity into the foreground.  Try your code in onResume() which runs immediately following onCreate() or when the activity is brought back into the foreground.  If you want to get really fancy, put your text size adjustment into a buildUI() method which can be called programmatically as soon as the user changes the pref.  You can also use it in your onResume() or onCreate().

Comment: Because this is a configuration activity where user selects the text size for a homescreen widget, and after he chooses the size and closes the activity, the widget should update.

Comment: I understand that, but I have to reiterate:  why do you set the text size in onPause()?  Have you tried moving the code to onResume()?  Think about it... user launches widget -> user clicks prefs -> widget.onPause() -> prefs activity launches -> user changes prefs -> user returns to widget -> widget.onResume() runs.  What am I missing?

Comment: This is settings.onPause not widget.onPause. Anyway my question is how to force widget update?

Answer (score 1):

You should just use the following method.

```
remoteViews.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.textView, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
```

I know its late. But, i hope it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my app.

```
// Update the widget
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Widget.class);
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
int[] ids = { R.xml.widget };
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then in your app widget provider onUpdate (after setting up remote views):

```
//appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, Widget.class), views);
```

The first one is what the docs say to do. I found the second one worked as expected.